# Load external images efficiency

Tags: c#, html, image, performance, caching

I would like to know a most efficient way to load external images to my website.

For example:
My website's url is "www.mydomain.com". The external image is `http://www.myimagedomain.com/image.jpg`.
The most common way is to write a simple html image-tag like 
`<img src="http://www.myimagedomain.com/image.jpg" />`.

The problem is, if the requested image is very large (8000x6000 pixel) but I want to show this picture as a thumbnail/preview like 200x200 pixel, e.g on mobile devices.

Based on this information I wrote a little ashx (c#) handler that downloads the requested image and resizes it to a given weight/height parameters, like this:

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/img.ashx?imageUrl=http://www.myimagedomain.com/image.jpg&w=200&h=200" />
```

Now there is another problem, because the httphandler always downloads the requested image, on-the-fly.

My new approach is to generate a based64 string from the resized image and save this in a database once?!
Would you recommend this or is there another way to eliminated the download problem? 
Maybe someone know how google-image-search prevents this problem?

I don't want to save the external images on my own server...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use image resizer library, it solves much of what you need in efficient way - caching included:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/

I think google caches image thumbnails on its servers for search.